# Running mahout jar on emr gives Wrong FS error for s3n://*/ input link

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mahout, emr

I need to run the **seqdirectory** command on emr.
I created a Fatjar(without specifying any main class) including the mahout-integration-0.9, mahout-core-0.9 and the commons-cli-2.0-mahout jar files.

and gave the following jar arguments-

org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory -i s3n://mybucket/dataset/2013-04-20-22/txt/ -o s3n://mybucket/sequence_files/ -c UTF-8

It gives a wrong FS msg on stderr-

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Wrong FS: s3n://trecdata/dataset/2013-04-20-22/txt, expected: hdfs://172.31.27.158:9000**
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.runMapReduce(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:162)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.run(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)*

and this on syslog-

*2015-07-13 21:34:18,684 INFO org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob (main): Command line arguments: {--charset=[UTF-8], --chunkSize=[64], --endPhase=[2147483647], --fileFilterClass=[org.apache.mahout.text.PrefixAdditionFilter], --input=[s3n://trecdata/dataset/2013-04-20-22/txt/], --keyPrefix=[], --method=[mapreduce], --output=[s3n://trecdata/sequence_files/], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
2015-07-13 21:34:19,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation (main): mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
2015-07-13 21:34:19,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation (main): mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
2015-07-13 21:34:19,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation (main): mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir*

Comment: Are you using Hadoop 2.x?  Mahout 0.9 is not compatible with Hadoop 2.x.

Comment: yeah I was using Hadoop 2.x. After switching to Hadoop 1.0.3 I get this error-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This file system object (hdfs://*:9000) does not support access to the request path 's3n://mybucket/dataset/2013-04-20-22/txt' You possibly called FileSystem.get(conf) when you should have called FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path.

Comment: I would suggest Upgrading to Mahout 0.10.1 which supports Hadoop 2 (and has several other bugfixes) rather than downgrading Hadoop. You should be able to  run `seqdirectory` with the `-xm sequential` option if you want to read/write directly to/from `s3n`. To run in MapReduce mode you'll have to put your data into HDFS.

Comment: yupp thanks. the -xm sequential option worked.but I had to transfer files to hdfs for other subsequent commands to run cvb. Is this the right way to do this ? -`distcp s3n://mybucket/folder/  hdfs://namenode ip:port/folder` , where the namenode ip:port was the value of `fs.default.name` property in conf/core-site.xml

Comment: Yeah that looks right.. see: [Hadoop Wiki- AmazonS3](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3).  You'll probably want to run the whole pipeline from HDFS.  the  `-xm sequential` option kinda defeats the purpose of running on a cluster.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also pls help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481304/mahout-cvb-faulty-output-gives-nan-values-for-topic-terms-and-no-probabilities)